# Better way to find value in comma separated string (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, regex

Assuming a String as defined:

```
String list = "apples,orange,bears,1,100,20,apple";
```

Without separating the list out into a collection or array, is there a better way to find a String in the list? For instance, if I search for `"bear",` there should be no result, since there would be no exact match (`bears` doesn't count). You can't look for "`,bear,"` since there's no guarantee that the word bear would not appear at the beginning or end of the file.

Comment: Just a question...why you don't want to split in an array? I think you will have more control on what your are searching and the code would be clear and look more professional, that adding commas or some kind or workarounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could still use something like:

```
(^|,)bears(,|$)
```

It will look for the commas, or the beginning or end of the line, which I believe is what you're looking for.

**EDIT: Addendum**

Since Denomales mentioned it, the above regex search will consume any commas (if any) that it can find, so that you will get overlapping matches in the case of lists like `apples,orange,bears,honey,bears,bears,bears,bears,9999,bees` and will count only 3 bears out of the 5 present. What you can do in this case is use lookarounds. It might take a bit to get your head around them, but the gist of it is that they look behind, or ahead of characters without consuming them. This thus makes it possible to find all the 5 bears, and this is how you use them:

```
(?<=^|,)bears(?=,|$)
```

A breakdown of characters...

`^` means the beginning of a line, so that in case there are no commas, you will still get a match.

`,` is a literal comma.

`(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind and will look behind the `b` character in `bears` to make sure there is what's inside, that is either a `^` or a `,`.

`(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead and will look after the `s` character in `bears` to make sure there is what's inside, that is either a `,` or a `$`.

`$` means the end of a line, working very much like `^`, but at the end.

Comment: This will skip ever other instance of your search term. The expression `(^|,)bears(,|$)` would only find two `bears` in the string  `apples,bears,bears,bears,bears,dogs`

Comment: @Denomales I didn't consider lookarounds (so as not to consume commas) because the OP seemed pretty positive about looking for "a String". Otherwise, lookarounds are the way to go. But if you insist, I guess I could add it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lookahead and a lookbehind to check what is around the searched word without capturing * . Example:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=,|^)bears(?=,|$)");
```

*(* however if you want to only check the presence of the word "bears", it isn't very important)*

Comment: This solution would find all 4 `bears` in the string `apples,bears,bears,bears,bears,dogs` and also automatically trims the leading/trailing commas. +1

Comment: @Denomales: When you find a bear, other bears are never far away.

Answer (score 2):

add ',' in the begining and at the end of the string

```
newList = ",apples,orange,bears,1,100,20,apple,";
```

then you can search for `,bear,`

Comment: This will skip ever other instance of your search term. The expression `(^|,)bears(,|$)` would only find two `bears` in the string  `apples,bears,bears,bears,bears,dogs`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want to look to see **if** the match occurs or **where** the match occurs. The easiest way to see **if** a match occurs is to call

```
list.matches("(^|(.*,))bear((,.*)|$)");
```

The `^` checks to see if bear is at the beginning of the string. The `|` means or. The `.*` looks for zero or more characters and the `,` simply looks for a comma. The `$` represents the end of the string. The parenthesis are used as matching conditions but aren't necessarily part of what you want to look for (i.e. the `bear`). For more information look at Java's `Pattern` class.

If you want to know where it occurs this is an easy way.

```
String list = "apples,orange,bear,1,100,20,apple";//Notice that I made "bear" singular
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile((?<=^|,)bear(?=,|$));//Compile the regex
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(list);//The text you want to search in
// Check all occurrences
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
}
```

which prints

```
Start index: 14 End index: 18 Found: bear
```

Both of these solutions use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Add **`','`** in the beginning and at the end of the string

This solution has a problem.
 
This adding of **`','`** before and after of both the strings to be compared requires concatenation of String. This means creation of **`2*2=4`** new String objects. That's very bad on performance point of view.